# Django ValueError at /admin/, even after flush

Tags: django

I'm setting up an Django application with react, redux and the django-rest-framework. After adding a "Customer" model within Django, I got an ValueError when accessing the admin interface.

The error keeps returning even after removing all the models from the admin interface by removing the line:
`admin.site.register(model)`.

Even when I flush the database, the error keeps returning.

I used the django User model with a knox token to log into the django application.

This is an local django installation within a pipenv.

error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 2.1.5
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'leads',
 'rest_framework',
 'frontend',
 'knox',
 'accounts',
 'customer']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  241.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  213.                 if request.path == reverse('admin:logout', current_app=self.name):

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  58.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in app_dict
  477.             self._populate()

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _populate
  430.                     url_pattern._populate()

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _populate
  419.                     bits = normalize(url_pattern.pattern.regex.pattern)

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py" in normalize
  153.                 count, ch = get_quantifier(ch, pattern_iter)

File "/home/[NAME]/.local/share/virtualenvs/lead_manager-2CdCcx2v/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py" in get_quantifier
  265.     return int(values[0]), ch

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'id'
```

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'leads',
    'rest_framework',
    'frontend',
    'knox',
    'accounts',
    'customer',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',)
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'leadmanager.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Model:

```
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")

class CustomerManager(models.Manager):

    def create_customer(self, username, password, first_name, last_name, email, phone, country, city, zip, address):
        customer = self.create(username=username, password=password, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, phone=phone, country=country, city=city, zip=zip, address=address)
        return customer

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)
    country = CountryField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='City')
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    objects = CustomerManager()

    def verify_password(self, raw_password):
        return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(raw_password, self.password)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

My expected results are to get access to the Django Admin interface without errors.
I hope that I have given all the information needed to resolve this problem.

Edit:
urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('', include('leads.urls')),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('customer.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Can you post the urls.py and the admin.py?

Comment: I have added the urls.py from the main project. I have multiple apps within django itself. None of the models are registered and all the admin.py files within these apps are empty.

Comment: It seems to be an error during the logout...you says that have flush the db...have you some users? Maybe a superuser that can access the admin interface? Try to open the login directly, or clean the cache of the browser

Comment: There weren't any users but i've made one now. When i directly go to the admin login page, I get the same error. When clearing the cache or using another browser the error keeps showing. I will try to look at the database and code and check if can spot an error.

Comment: Using the code that you posted I can access the admin without problem. I removed some parts because some referenced code was missing. For example in the urls I have only the admin, and in the model I removed the `CountryField`, the `status `and the `verify_password` (I don't know from where come `pbkdf2_sha256`). Also I don't have `frontend`, `accounts` and `customer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the mistake after hours of reading and troubleshooting. The error wasn't in the admin, model or api. It was in my urls.py from the accounts app.

This was the code I used:

```
path('api/auth/user/{id}', GetUserAPI.as_view()),
```

instead of

```
path('api/auth/user/<id>', GetUserAPI.as_view()),
```

Thanks for the help in troubleshooting the given error!